# Passing Data to a Controller by Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult RecipeDetails(string recipeString)
    {
        RecipeModel Recipe = new RecipeModel(recipeString);

        return View(Recipe);
    }
```

When I tried to use an `ActionLink()` like this, the value of `recipeString` would be `null`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Recipe.RecipeName.ToString(), "RecipeDetails", "Recipe", Recipe.RecipeName }, null)
```

But when I changed it to this, it passed the correct value:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Recipe.RecipeName.ToString(), "RecipeDetails", "Recipe", new { RecipeString = Recipe.RecipeName }, null)
```

Why exactly is that?  Why can't I just pass the `string` as-is as a route value to the controller??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't know what to do with Recipe.RecipeName, just that it is a string, by providing `new { RecipeString = Recipe.RecipeName }` you are basically telling it add `&RecipeString=(value of Recipe.RecipeName)` to the query string

Comment: Great answer.  The difference is that you need to pass a set of key/value pairs as your third parameter, which will then get converted into a query string. ex: new{ hello : "world" } would get added on as ?hello=world.